# sklearn train_test_split - ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn

I have a multi-label classification problem, for which I looked online and saw that for one-hot encoding the labels it is best to use the `MultiLabelBinarizer`.

I use this for my labels (which i separate from the dataset itself) as follows:

```
ohe = MultiLabelBinarizer()
labels = ohe.fit_transform(labels)
train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(dataset, labels, test_size=0.2) #80% train split
```

But it throws me this following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "learn.py", line 114, in <module> 
    train, test, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(dataset, labels, test_size=0.2) #80% train split
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py", line 2127, 
in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 293, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "C:\Users\xwb18152\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 256, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [83292, 5]
```

--

**EDIT:** The labels dataset looks as follows (ignore the `Interval` column, this shouldnt be there and is not actually counted in the rows -- not sure why?):

```
          Movement  Distance  Speed  Delay  Loss 
Interval
0                1         1     25      0     0
2                1         1     25      0     0
4                1         1     25      0     0
6                1         1     25      0     0
8                1         1     25      0     0
...            ...       ...    ...    ...   ...
260              3         5     50      0     0
262              3         5     50      0     0
264              3         5     50      0     0
266              3         5     50      0     0
268              3         5     50      0     0
```

From this we can see that it is a multi-label multi-class classification problem. The `shape` of the `dataset` and `labels` before and after the Binarizer are as follows:

```
             Before             After
dataset      (83292, 15)        (83292, 15)
labels       (83292, 5)         (5, 18)
```

Comment: What is the shape of `dataset` and `labels`

Comment: @NarendraPrasath before the binarizer the shape of `dataset` and `labels` is `(83292, 15)` and `(83292, 5)` and after the binarizer `(83292, 15)` and `(5, 18)` respectively.

Comment: @NarendraPrasath I have updated the OP to include more information.

Comment: I have given the solution. Hope that works well for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, labels orginal shape is `(83292, 5)` and once you applied `MultiLabelBinarizer` it became `(5, 18)`.

`train_test_split(X, y)` function expect that **X and y should have the same rows**. E.g: `83292` datapoints available in your `X` and respective datapoints label should be available in your `y` variable.
Hence, in your case it should be `X` and `y` shape should be `(83292, 15)` and `(83292, 18)`.

**Try this:**
Your `MultiLabelBinarizer` output having wrong dimension here. So, if your  `labels` is a dataframe object, then you should apply `mlb.fit_transform(labels.values.tolist())`.
this would produce the same no of rows as output here `83292`.

**Example of your labels should be like below format:**

your `y` input can be like `list of list` or dataframe having `one column which having list of values`. Make sure you have X and y having same no of rows. You can represent multi-label multi-class `y` variable like below format. Or dataframe.shape should be `(no_of_rows, 1)`

```
[[1, 1, 25, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 25, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 25, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 25, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 25, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 50, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 50, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 50, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 50, 0, 0],
 [3, 5, 50, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! However, the labels dataset goes from having shape `(83292, 5)` to `(83292, 14)` any idea why?

Comment: @rshah does this solution working? It is a representation of binary for every label. There will be `14` unique classes available. that's why the shape is 14

Comment: It passes the binarizer without error, but I have 5 classes, but I am wondering why now the labels and dataset have the same shape (after binarizing the labels) of `(83292, 14)`

Comment: @rshah can you check the total no of unique labels?

Comment: I checked what the output of `ohe.classes_` was, and it is not what I expected: `[  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  10  25  50 100 150 200]`

Comment: @rshah This are available classes in your y label. that's correct I guess. Probably your question doesn't fit with your expectations. But, whatever the issue stated in your OP has been fixed now I guess.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I have to work more on pre-processing.. perhaps change Movement to have values like 1, 2, 3, ... to split into more columns like Movement_1, Movement_2 etc.. so its easier for this.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the length of the various elements you're trying to split don't match.For `X` and `y`, `sklearn` will take the same indices, usually a random sample of 80% of the indices of your data. So, the lengths have to match.

Imagine it's trying to keep these indices. What would `sklearn` do when there's nothing at some index?

```
 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
 a b b a b a b a a b b b 
 ^   ^     ^ ^   ^   ^   ^ ^
```

Do this check to verify that the lengths match. Does this return `True`?

```
len(dataset) == len(labels)
```

Comment: Will I perform this comparison before or after the one-hot encoding using `MultiLabelBinarizer`?

Comment: Before or after doesn't matter, because this doesn't change the length of the data.

Comment: According to the `MultiLabelBinarizer` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html), a common mistake is to pass a list. Maybe this is where you went wrong?

Comment: By doing `len(dataset) == len(labels)` before using `MultiLabelBinarizer` it returns `True`, but returns false afterwards with the lengths being `83292` and `5` for dataset and labels, respectively.

Comment: According to the docs, the frequent mistake can be solved by doing `fit_transform([labels])`

Comment: I tried the solution you posed Nicolas, but it doesnt work. The length after doing this changes to 1 for labels. The datatype of labels before is `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and after the `MultiLabelBinarizer` this becomes `numpy.ndarray`.

Comment: Also, should I maybe be performing the `MultiLabelBinarizer` after doing the `train_test_split`? And would using the sckit.multilearn `iterative_train_test_split` be adviseable?

Comment: i think you need to select one column only, not an entire pandas dataframe